# Set notificationbar icon color

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio and want to match everything with my project colors.
How can I set the color of the icons in the notificationbar? Or if not possible hide only the icons, not the bar?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How can I set the color of the icons in the notificationbar?" -- AFAIK, while you can change the tint of the bar, the system handles the icons, to ensure a decent contrast. More importantly, the system handles the icons to prevent developers from trying to hide the icons by changing their color to match that of the bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

When building the notification, you can set the color and the icon. (If your icon is a pure white image, it'll apply the color for you in the correct spots.)

here is my code I have used recently

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
val notificationId = 10 // Some unique id.

// Creating a channel - required for O's notifications.
val channel = NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
        "Channel human-readable title",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

// Building the notification.
val builder = Notification.Builder(context, channel.id)
builder.setContentTitle("Warning!")
builder.setContentText("This is a bad notification!")
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.skull)
builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
builder.setChannelId(channel.id)

// Posting the notification.
manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
}
```

here in the first-line check the verion of your phone and according to that will get notification Style

builder. small icon and builder.set color(Give color you desire)